# Windows cmd: SETLOCAL ENDLOCAL not working as expected

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a subroutine like the following:

```
:RunProc
SETLOCAL


REM Some code here


:PROC_OK
set RetVal=0
goto PROC_END

:PROC_ERR
set RetVal=1
goto PROC_END


:PROC_END


ENDLOCAL & set ProcResult=%RetVal%
goto:eof
```

when I call it from other point of the cmd

```
CALL :RunProc %A% %B%

echo "%ProcResult%"
```

it doesn't return the %ProcResult% that instead is empty.

What is wrong?

Thanks,
Gianluca

Comment: Your code work for me. Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: While creating a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example I discover that it doesn't work if the call is inside an IF statement:
    IF "A"="B" (
    rem some code here
    ) else (
    CALL :RunProc %A% %B%
    
    echo "%ProcResult%"
    )

Comment: Do not add code in comments, [edit] your question instead. You need to use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. Currently `ProcResult` variable get expanded to its value before you call to subroutine.